# How to integrate my infinite loop with GTK+?

Tags: c++, gtk

I have a Raspberry Pi3 board and I have some sensors. I wanted to make a GUI and the shortest was gtk+ and C++. For example I got continuous ECG data. That function what gave me the data is on an infinite loop. I would like to update in real time the GTK labels. Could somebody solve the problem?
This the code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "eHealth.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//g++ -lpthread -lrt a.cpp arduPi.o eHealth.o -o a `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`


char c[256];
float ECG;


int i=0;
float looop(){
//here is the infinite loop
    while(1){
            ECG=eHealth.getECG();

        }
    return ECG;
}


static void button_clicked10(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(data), "u clicked10");
}

static void button_clicked11(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(data), "u clicked11");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
        GtkWidget *window, *label, *button, *table, *label10;
        window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

        table = gtk_table_new(8, 3, 10); //rows, columns, honogenous
        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button");

        ECG=eHealth.getECG();

        sprintf(c,"%f", looop());
        //in this label I want to print the ECG data
        label = gtk_label_new(c);  ///(!!!)

        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, 0,1,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 1,2,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 2");
        label = gtk_label_new("Hello World 2");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, 0,1,1,2, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 1,2,1,2, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 3");
        label = gtk_label_new("Hello World 3");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, 0,1,2,3, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 1,2,2,3, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);



        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 4");
        label = gtk_label_new("Hello World 4");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, 0,1,3,4, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 1,2,3,4, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);


        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 5");
        label = gtk_label_new("Hello World 5");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, 2,3,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 3,4,0,1, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);


        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 6");
        label = gtk_label_new("Hello World 6");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, 2,3,1,2, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 3,4,1,2, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);


        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 7");
        label10 = gtk_label_new("Hello World 7");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label10, 2,3,2,3, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 3,4,2,3, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked10), (gpointer)label10);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 8");
        label = gtk_label_new("Hello World 8");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, 2,3,3,4, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 3,4,3,4, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 9");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 0,4,4,5, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);


        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 10");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 0,4,5,6, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 11");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 0,4,6,7, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked11), (gpointer)label);
        button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Button 10");
        gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button, 0,4,7,8, GTK_FILL, GTK_FILL, 0,0);
        g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked10), (gpointer)label);

        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);


        gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 500, 500);
        gtk_widget_show_all(window);


        gtk_main();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: if you use C++ with gtk+ you might be better off using the gtk+ C++ bindings: [gtkmm](https://www.gtkmm.org/en/).

Comment: I developed this in codeblock, and I checked the codeblocks compile parameter, thats why I wrote as a comment that compile command.

Comment: You need to go back to basics and learn how GUI toolkits like GTK+ use event loops. You can't block them using your own `while` loop or such. Use a GLib timeout function to update your label on a schedule. @BotondDénes Weirdly, they are linking against `gtkmm`, but not making any use of its benefits...

Comment: @underscore_d right, didn't notice that. Then I recommend the use of the gtkmm API even more. :)

Answer (score 3):

GTK+ and its underlying libraries like GLib require to run their own main event loop. Any code of yours that alters GTK+/GLib stuff needs to then return, so that GTK+/GLib can deal with what you've asked them to do. If you block them using your own `while` or other loop, they can't do anything.

I won't dwell on this further as it's basic stuff; see, for example:

- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk3-General.description
- https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.description

You can resolve your question by using a GLib timeout source, to run the function that updates your label, on a desired schedule. There are [`g_timeout_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add), `g_timeout_add_seconds()`, and others documented at that page.

Here's a toy example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean
on_timeout (gpointer user_data)
{
  static unsigned f_times = 0;

  GtkLabel *label = GTK_LABEL (user_data);

  ++f_times;
  gchar *text = g_strdup_printf ("I have been updated %u times", f_times);
  gtk_label_set_label (label, text);
  g_free (text);

  return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE; /* or G_SOURCE_REMOVE when you want to stop */
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new ("not updated yet...");
  g_timeout_add (1000 /* milliseconds */, on_timeout, label);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), label);
  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Some other points:

- You don't mention which GTK+ version you're using. I assume 3, as 2 is too old to be using for new code. In that case, note that `GtkTable` is deprecated in GTK+ 3 and gone in GTK+ 4; you should be using `GtkGrid` instead. See [Migrating from other containers to GtkGrid](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkGrid.html)
- Your compiler is linking against `gtkmm`, the official C++ bindings for GTK+, yet you have written all your code to call the C library directly. That seems a bit odd. `gtkmm` is great, so I can recommend it, but if you don't want it, then you should state your intent by using C and linking against GTK+. But obviously, my code assumes you really want C.

Comment: I used  GTK+ 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this using GTK2, check https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/gui_toolkit_guides/gtk+_gnome_application_development/sec-mainloop.html

You can use gtk_main_iteration();

````
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
   Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
   Gtk::Window win;
   Gtk::Frame m_Frame;
   m_Frame.set_label("Gtk::Frame Widget");
   win.add(m_Frame);
   win.set_default_size(900,600);
   win.set_title("Loop App");
   win.set_border_width(10);
   win.show_all_children();
```win.show();

  while(1){
    while (gtk_events_pending())
        gtk_main_iteration();
    /*Do your work*/
    /*Do your work 2*/
    }
}
````